# Conditional expectation properties proof

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am trying to understand the proofs of the properties of conditional expectation.

I first start with the definition of conditional expectation:

let $X$ be an integrable r.v. on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ and $\mathcal G\subset \mathcal F$ a sigma-algebra.

Then a r.v. $Y=\mathbb E(X|\mathcal G)$, $\mathcal G$-measurable function for which holds $\mathbb E(XI_A)=\mathbb E(YI_A)$ for each $A\in \mathcal G$ is called conditional expectation of X given $\mathcal G$.

Now, if I want to prove the "pull out what is known" I have to prove: $\mathbb E(XY|\mathcal G)=Y\mathbb E(X|\mathcal G)$ if Y is $\mathcal G$-measurable

How to prove this? Do I have to show that $\mathbb E(XY|\mathcal G)$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable and that $\mathbb E(XYI_A)=\mathbb E(\mathbb E(XY|\mathcal G)I_A) $?

I have no clue, I see everywhere on the proofs I find that "clearly $ Y\mathbb E(X|\mathcal G)$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable", why?

If I use the definition of conditional expectation I may say that $\mathbb E(X|\mathcal G)$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, and that Y is same by the assumptions, but I don't know what happens to their product.

The second point I don't understand is that we can prove the equality if we show $\mathbb E(Y\mathbb E(X|\mathcal G)I_A)=\mathbb E(XYI_A)$. The steps after this I can understand but I don't know why I have to show this.

To me these two quantities can be re-written as $\mathbb E (\mathbb E(XY|\mathcal G)I_A)=\mathbb E(YXI_A)$

I tried to ask the prof and he said that we need to show that the property is a conditional expectation by checking the measurability and then the equation on top for each A, but for me it's very confusing.

Comment: If you do not know that the product of two measurable random variables is again measurable, then you should have a look at the first chapters of a book on measure theory before trying to understand conditional expectations.

Comment: that I didn't know, and may you please give me an hint of what I need to understand that to prove the property I can simply prove $E(XYI_A)=E(YE(X|G)I_A)$?

Comment: Note that an integrable $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $Z$ equals $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{X} \mid \mathcal{G})$ if, and only if $$\mathbb{E}(1_A \tilde{X}) = \mathbb{E}(1_A Z)$$ for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$. Apply this with $\tilde{X} := XY$ and $Z := Y \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G})$.

Comment: Thank you very much, and that I can know from the definition of conditional expectation? I mean, it's like going backwards, saying if $\mathbb E(XI_A)=\mathbb E(YI_A)$ and Y is $\mathcal G-$measurable, then $Y=\mathbb E(X|\mathcal G)$. A last thing, when we don't specify any variable in the indicator function, like $I_A$, we mean that $I(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\in A$, is that correct? If, for instance, we have $I(\omega)_{\{\tau(\omega)=i\}}$ we mean that $I=1$ if $\omega \in \Omega: \tau(\omega)=i$   ?   with   $\tau(\omega)$ another r.v.

Comment: Yes, this follows directly from the definition of conditional expectation. And yes, if we write $1_A$ (or $I_A$), then we mean $1_A(\omega)$ ($I_A(\omega)$, resp.).

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to do it in four parts: prove it for constant functions, simple functions, positive functions, then all functions. I'm pretty sure you'll also need the dominated convergence theorem. Many examples of this 4-part style proof can surely be found in whatever textbook you're using (if you're not using one, let me know and I'll link you one).

This should've been a comment but I didn't have enough rep to make one.. sorry about that. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I looked at 4-5 different course notes on the web, and I have the book "A first look at rigorous probability" because I think the author tries to let people really understand. But still, he starts the proof with "clearly $YE(X|G)$ is $G-$measurable. I am also ok by proving that only for $Y=I_B$ with $B\in G$, so I don't need monotone or dominated convergence. Is it really 2 lines but what is obvious for the author is not for me.

Comment: $E(X|G)$ is $G$-measurable from the definition. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967212/understanding-the-measurability-of-conditional-expectations?rq=1

Comment: That I agree with, but what about the product $YE(X|G)$? Why can I state that it's still $G$-measurable? Also for me is not so clear what I can use from the definition of conditional expectation and what I have to prove to state the property. Thanks for the link but it didn't help